# Flutter: setState in TextButton not working

Tags: android, flutter, dart, setstate

**Dice image not changing on onPress** 
***setState*** not setting dice image for random number

**child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftDiceNumber.png'),**  not working but
**child: Image.asset('images/dice2.png'),** is working that means hard code is working
**var leftDiceNumber = 3;** getting only dice3.png as i initialize it for leftDiceNumber

*Please help for getting random image when onPress*

---

*No errors in App*

```
class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DicePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var leftDiceNumber = 3;
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {   
                  leftDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                  print(leftDiceNumber); // getting value in console
                });
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftDiceNumber.png'),  
                      //child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'), // ( works )
            ),),],
      ),);}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because every time you call `setState()` it calls the `build` method, and you have defined `leftDiceNumber = 3` inside the `build` method. So even though the `setState()` changes the value it again gets set to 3.

**Solution:** Move `var leftDiceNumber = 3;` outside the build method.

```dart
class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  var leftDiceNumber = 3;
  
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YourWidget();
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add the initState method and the solution is perfect

Comment: If we can initialize variables without doing the following wouldn't it make it simpler?
`late variableName;` and then `initState(){variableName = value;}`
I'm new to flutter. I'm guessing that using `initState()` is a good practice even if it is for a simple variable like this. Please enlighten me.